# Can I change figure size when I use facet_wrap or grid in R?

Tags: r

Is there parameters that I can change the figure sizes ( width, height ) when I use facet_wrap or facet_grid in R?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the margins within the `theme` function, where you only have to adjust the parameters depending on what you want to change.

```
ggplot() + 
  theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 0.5,  # Top margin
                             r = 5.5,  # Right margin
                             b = 0.5,  # Bottom margin
                             l = 5.5,  # Left margin
                             unit = "cm"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
but if I want to make it fig.width=7, fig.height=5 this requirement, how can I make it with margin?